# What bin value does QGIS Histogram uses?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, ndvi, histogram

I have some single-band rasters (NDVI) on QGIS, for which I can obtain their distribution histogram by going to `Right-click > Properties > Histogram Tab > Compute Histogram`. This is an example of what I get:

[image]

This is the same procedure (and also works) for multi-band images (RGB etc). However, **I wonder what is the default bin size that QGIS used to calculate and render this histogram?** I obtained this histogram without modifying any setting on the Prefs/Actions tab.

In the case of RGB images surely the bin size should be `>=1`, as pixels can only be in the discrete interval of `[0,255]` and it wouldn't make sense to have a lower bin size (say, 0.5 pixel value).

However, in the case of NDVI and similar indexes non-integer bin sizes are viable, even more given that the NDVI lies between `[-1,1]`. So, I wonder how QGIS determines this bin size, as I need to know what value was used to properly compare with other histograms I produce manually.

I am using QGIS 2.14.12-Essen

Comment: I line 326 of https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/1135941ecaf780c9dc5a3c968693d966b4bd838d/src/core/raster/qgsrasterinterface.h is says: binCount Number of bins (intervals,buckets). If 0, the number of bins is decided automatically according to data type, raster size etc

Comment: In line +339 of https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/fb9df9f6debc80d6e89edf2c9593822822933419/src/core/raster/qgsrasterinterface.cpp: You have listed different ways of calculating bins

Comment: Pedantic, maybe, but it looks like a line chart rather than a histogram. (A histogram would make more sense.)

Comment: @Jakob digging a bit yesterday I came upon one of those links you mentioned.... maybe what you say could be worked into an answer?

Comment: @Jakob took the time to put my finding and the useful input you gave here into an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some browsing and with some input from Jakob on comments, we have these two links that give some insight on the way QGis decides the bin count.

On [this link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/1135941ecaf780c9dc5a3c968693d966b4bd838d/src/core/raster/qgsrasterinterface.h#L326) it's stated in a comment, emphasis mine:

> \param binCount Number of bins (intervals,buckets). **If 0, the number of bins is decided automatically** according to data type, raster size etc.

Then on [this other link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/fb9df9f6debc80d6e89edf2c9593822822933419/src/core/raster/qgsrasterinterface.cpp#L339) we can see the actual code where `binCount` is calculated, if unspecified by the histogram call. Summing up what's specified there:

- If the data type is Byte, then the binCount is 256.
- If data type is Integer, then the binCount is calculated like this (pseudocode):

  - `min((hist.width * hist.height) , ceiling(hist.maximum - hist.minimum +1))`
- If data type is else (float, double, etc.) then binCount is: `hist.width * hsit.height`.

We also have these comments worth mentioning here:

> // There is no best default value, to display something reasonable in histogram chart,binCount should be small, OTOH, to get precise data for cumulative cut, the number should be big.

> // Because it is easier to define fixed lower value for the chart, we calc optimum binCount for higher resolution (to avoid calculating that where histogram() is used. In any case, it does not make sense to use more than width*height;

Finally, the histogram height and width are calculating depending on the sample size and the resolution of the image to obtain the histogram from. The code for that can be found on [these lines](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/fb9df9f6debc80d6e89edf2c9593822822933419/src/core/raster/qgsrasterinterface.cpp#L307).